# PowerPivot - relating data by date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerpivot, powerquery

Does anyone know what DAX function I should use to display information from one table in another table.

I've got 2 tables in my data model:

**Tasks**
- Task ID
 - Task Name
 - Start Date
 - End Date

**Fiscal Periods**
- ID
- Period Name
- Start Date
- End Date

What I'm trying to do is for each Task, add a calculated column the is populated with the corresponding Fiscal Period ID. I'm trying to add a filter or calculation that specifies:
- if the task start date is between Fiscal Start Date and Fiscal End Date, return the fiscal period id.

Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks,
Ro

Comment: This link has a more flexible way of implementing what you are looking for... http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2011/11/the-ultimate-date-table/

Comment: could you upload some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

1. In case Fiscal Period ID is a number:

`=CALCULATE(MAX(Periods[ID]),FILTER(Periods,Periods[Start Date]<=Tasks[Start Date] && Periods[End Date]>=Tasks[Start Date]))`

2. In case Fiscal Period ID is not a number:

Put Start Date to calculated column first, say 'Period Start Date'

`=CALCULATE(MAX(Periods[Start Date]),FILTER(Periods,Periods[Start Date]<=Tasks[Start Date] && Periods[End Date]>=Tasks[Start Date]))`

and then use `LOOKUPVALUE` for ID

`=LOOKUPVALUE(Periods[ID],Periods[Start Date],Tasks[Period Start Date])`